# Update query in Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am writing a simple method to update a record using spring jdbc the method is

```
 @Override
public void updateEmployee(Employee e, int id) {
    try {
        Connection connection = DemoApplicationServiceImpl.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String update = "UPDATE salesforce.Employee__c SET First_Name__c = " + e.getFirst() + ", Last_Name__c = "
                + e.getLast() + ", Email__c = " + e.getEmail() + " WHERE Id = " + id;
        System.out.println(update);
        statement.executeQuery(update);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It gives me an error

```
 psqlexception column "umair" does not exist
```

umair is not even a column in database

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing Spring about this, it's just basic JDBC. A really bad example on what not to do. Always use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`.

Comment: maybe you need to add '(quotes) after = in sql query.
maybe use prepared statement and set parameters with it if you don't want to deal with it..

Comment: Seriously??? *NEVER CONCATENATE SQL STATEMENTS*! Read up on SQL-injection. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution can cause SQL Injection or Syntax error, instead use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) it is more secure and more helpful :

```
String update = "UPDATE salesforce.Employee__c SET First_Name__c = ?, Last_Name__c = ?, Email__c = ? WHERE Id = ? ";
try (PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(update)) {
    pstm.setString(1, e.getFirst());
    pstm.setString(2, e.getLast());
    pstm.setString(3, e.getEmail());
    pstm.setInt(4, id);

    pstm.executeUpdate();
}
```

---

About your Error :

You get that error because you try to use something like this :

```
SET First_Name__c = umair
```

But String or varchar should be between two quotes :

```
SET First_Name__c = 'umair'
//------------------^_____^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String update = "UPDATE salesforce.Employee__c SET First_Name__c = '" + e.getFirst() + "', Last_Name__c = '"
            + e.getLast() + "', Email__c = '" + e.getEmail() + "' WHERE Id = " + id;
```

When comparing fields to string values (and other values in general), you need to use quotes, like FIELD = 'Value'.

But as others said, is better to always use PreparedStatement
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html